# Facebook comments view embed in webview android

Tags: android, facebook, comments

I want to add the facebook comments functionality in my application so I embedded a div tag in a webview obtained from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ with html tags of course.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="example.com" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

Everything works fine except the multiple login. 
Facebook login works nicely, however when I try to login with hotmail and yahoo it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and why the other logins don't work? and only facebook does?

Comment: Hi,
Did you get a solution for this. I'm also having the same issue as well.

Comment: @hariKJ no, didn't get it working.

Answer (score -1):

Make a local HTML file that you load from the webview that has your code from above.